# Access Denied trying to create Solr Config

Tags: solr, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm following the example at:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/examples/retrieve_and_rank_solr.v1.js

But everytime I try and upload a config I get 
"Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

I've made an API key for Retrieve and Rank, are there more things to do to manage the credentials for R&R?

Here's my code:

```
return retrieveInstance.uploadConfigAsync({
  cluster_id: clusterId,
  config_name: watsonConfig.config_name,
  config_zip_path: (__dirname + "/../../" + watsonConfig.config_path)
});
```

I'm successfully creating a cluster with this API key.
Schema.zip has this schema.xml

```
<schema name="simple" version="1.5">
<fields>
   <!-- required -->
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="question" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="answer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ms"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_mi"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
  </types>
</schema>
```

Comment: Make sure you have credentials for the service(they are not your bluemix email and password) and they are the ones the node-sdk is using. You can do `NODE_DEBUG=request app.js` to check the HTTP calls your app is making.

Answer (score 0):

Details on how to access the credentials can be found here : https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/tutorial.shtml#credentials

To sum up, from the Bluemix web dashboard, if you click on your R&R service instance, the "Service Credentials" tab will show a username and password. These will not be your IBM ID username or password.

[image: screenshot of getting the service credentials]

That said, if you've been able to create a cluster, that would suggest that you have got valid credentials. Are you sure that the cluster was created successfully? Can you confirm this by getting the cluster details using the curl command described at https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/?curl#list_solr_clusters ?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I met the same problem. Use the cranfield-solr-config.zip in Tutorial and replace its original config file (schema.xml...) with your config file. But do not uncompress the zip file and compress it again!!! I do not know why this happens, but it does...